# How do I program grab to capture a window in applescript xcode

Tags: xcode, window, applescript

I need to make the application "Grab" capture a window with applescript in xcode 3.2. What could be the script for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not found anything directly useable in the AppleScript World, so I would suggest to use `screencapture` - a command line tool - and call that from your script. 
Execute `man screencapture` in **Terminal.app** to see its manUAL.

Side-Note: the AppleScript Command to do shell scripting is `do shell script` (from "StandardAdditions").

("Grab" does not support AppleScript)

Comment: @Tom Open an application with the Apple Script Editor to see if it has an Apple Script Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The following applescript code will take a screenshot of a section of the screen and save it to a file on the desktop. As mentioned above it uses the screenshot application.

```
set x1 to 0
set x1 to x1 + 1
set thename to "screencapture -x -R20,20,640,380 ~/Desktop/screen_" & x1 & ".png"

tell application "Terminal"

activate

do script thename in window 1

end tell
```